# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function. How do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, typeerror

I was using React when I got the following error.

`TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function`

How do I solve this?
I have added the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './loginForm'
import useState from "react"

function LoginPage(){
    const[details, setDetails] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    });
    function handleChange(event){
        const updatedDetails = {...details, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
        setDetails(updatedDetails)
    }
    return(<LoginForm details={details} onChange={handleChange}/>)
};

export default LoginPage;
```

The other component is :-

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Jumbotron, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';

function FormPage(props){
  return (
    <Jumbotron fluid>
    <Container fluid>
    <center><h1 className="display-3"> Log IN</h1></center>
    <p className="lead">Please Enter your Details Here</p>
    </Container><br />
    <Container fluid>
    <Form>
        <FormGroup>
            <Label for="username">Username</Label>
            <Input type="textarea" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your Username Here" value={props.details.username} onChange={props.onChange}></Input>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <Label for="password">Password</Label>
            <Input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password Here" value={props.details.username} onChange={props.onChange}></Input>
        </FormGroup>
        <Button color="success">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
    </Container>
    </Jumbotron>
  );
};

export default FormPage;
```

PS: I am typing this because StackOverflow is asking me to add some more details as my question is mostly code. Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am just going to point out you are importing from "react" lib twice

```
// You have: (look closely at libs you are importing from and how)
import React from 'react';
import LoginForm from './loginForm'
import useState from "react"

// Should be:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LoginForm from './loginForm'

// Why?
// Because useState is one of React libs' export default's apis / methods
// aka useState is just a part of the React default export but also is itself, an export
// React.useState() is how it would look if you just imported the React lib itself and nothing else
// how I personally handle any react apis is via ==> 
import React, { useState } from 'react

// apart from loving seeing all libraries and individual apis imported 
// as soon as I see a file to get a sense of its potential functionalities, 
// read my detailed explanation below
```

Here, you are literally importing (`export default react`) from the entire React lib and simply naming it a random string useState and then trying to use that how you use the real `React.useState()` api/method.

So you trying to use useState like the actual React `useState` api in this manner will absolutely cause an error because you are basically saying this `require('react')()` when you import the default import of react lib versus an api that is part of that default export, or it is itself an export in which you need to deconstruct from the lib in the import statement, not sure related but you 100% have malformed code I cannot believe no one even mentioned this?

For further example, for it to work as you have it (although eslint should be screaming about duplicate imports by now before you even hit save) you would have to do `useState.useState()`, which clearly is not what you want. Some people don't mind `React.useState()` but I personally will shun you haha jk, but destruct from import!!! please (:

***Using Best Coding Standards*** is key to being a great software engineer on a team and even in your own personal projects for all of the reasons, and will absolutely increase your DX and output overall.

Hope this helped my dude. We all have gone through these little quirks that once you learn, add that to your "things I know for sure" list and keep trucking

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both for the answer and for the detailed information.

Comment: sure thing man, always practice coding best standards in both FE and BE code. React has a few paradigms when it comes to data you can go with, but whichever way follow the standards and the code should be clean - by "clean" I mean extremely readable

Answer (score 4):

Please add more information. Like what was the API/module you choose to import and is it using

```
export default function
```

vs

```
export function
```

How you are consuming it?

You might have importing it as

```
import Something from './something';
```

Whereas, your something.js might look like:

```
export function Something(){
}
```

Comment: This was the issue for me. A simple thing to overlook when you are trying to work on too many files at once!

Answer (score 1):

If you updated webpack to version 5.x.x, then this might be related to [output.library setting issue](https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-webpack-imported-module-is-not-a-function-for-webpack5/)

so if you have library setting in webpack output try to remove it:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: 'painterro.commonjs2.js',
  library: 'Painterro',  // ⏪ this is the issue
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

when you import useTheme just put useTheme inside the curly braces

import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to post the code in the file throwing this error.
With this info as it is, it is possible that you imported something as a default import yet there is nothing exported as default from the module in question. Try to investigate the default exports and see if one of them has no default exports. You could look up the module documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Under similar circumstances I got the above error on Next running under Yarn. When I added a new page the issue appeared. The only thing that solved it was running
`yarn upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone but one of the reasons for this error is that you are trying to initialize a function which is not defined. Usually this happens because you are not importing a function properly. You can try importing a function as import {function} from "library" instead of import function from "library". In my case, the error was occurring because I imported getCookie function from next-cookies as - import getCookie from 'cookies-next'. getCookie is not an export default function. All I needed to do was to import it like - import {getCookie} from 'cookies-next' to fix the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this will help or not but, I was facing the same problem, when I was calling a function within react useReducer hook initilizer and throwing the same error.
Later I realized that I did not exported those functions. Exporting them solved the issue.

**Example**
Exporting functions from Utils.js to Working.js, to utilize it there.

```
  // Util.js

  const someUtilFunc1 = () => {
     // code here...
  }

  const someUtilFunc2 = () => {
     // code here...
  }
  

/* THIS LINE WAS MISSING */
export { someUtilFunc1, someUtilFunc2 };
```

```
  // Working.js
  import { React, useReducer } from "react";
  import { someUtilFunc1, someUtilFunc2 } from './Utils.js';
  
  // Utilize here
  

  const initializer = (someState) => {
   
  return (
    /* THIS WAS THROWING ERROR (not a function) */
    someUtilFunc1(someState)
  )
   
  }
  const Component = () => {
  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [], initializer);

  }
```

After adding the exporting line in Util.js, Solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Well...in my case ... I realized that I forgot to to put the extension of the file. so the compiler was acting weird.. I put myfilename.js and everything worked well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

after installing new package maybe you haven't re-run the project