# TypeError: util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a `server.js` file that opens a database with node. I'm trying to import this into an index.js file through a `lib` directory and I have two files in it:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import addName from "util";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("")

  function handleUpdate(evt) {
    setName(evt.target.value);
  }

  async function handleAddName(evt) {
    await addName(name);
  }

  return <div>
    <p><input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleUpdate} /></p>
    <button className='button-style' onClick={handleAddName}>Add Name</button>
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

```js
// util.js
import "isomorphic-fetch"

export function addName(name) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/add-time', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, time: Date.now() })
    })
}
```

This gives me:

```
TypeError: util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...) is not a function.
```

I didn't think it would make much of a difference, but on line three of the `App.js` file I added two curly brackets to make it `import {addName} from "util";`.

This then gives me the error: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. Both of these are pointing to *line 13* of `App.js`, `await addName(name);`. Now, I'm exporting the `addName(name)` function from `util.js, so I don't understand what this error is.

When I googled the errors, it seemed to lead me to answers that didn't really work for my situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: react\_\_WEBPACK\_IMPORTED\_MODULE\_2\_\_\_default(...) is not a function. How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142136/typeerror-react-webpack-imported-module-2-default-is-not-a-function-ho)

Comment: Not quite.. I see what the first answer is saying I think, but as I'm only importing one thing from each place, I'm that answer doesn't work in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
import addName from "util";
```

you're importing the *default export* from `util`. But what you exported was a *named export* here:

```
export function addName(name) {
```

Either use a default export instead:

```
export default function addName(name) {
```

Or import the named one instead:

```
import { addName } from 'util';
```

Comment: After trying `import { addName } from "util";` and trying `export default function addName(name)` it still gave me the same issue

Comment: Is `util` really in `node_modules`? That's the only time you should use the bare path. If it's in the same directory as your `App.js`, you should import it with `import { addName } from './util'` or `import addName from './util'` - with the `./` in front.